# How to concatenate single dimensions in multidimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, valueerror

```
lows = np.array([0 for lead in range(10)])

temp_lows = np.array([[1 for points in range(12)] for lead in range(10)]) # Ones are only a placeholder. temp_lows is filled with random int (data)

for lead in range(10):
    lows[lead] = np.concatenate((lows[lead], temp_lows[lead]), axis=None)
```

After executing, it returns:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Basically I want the lows array to be the big array, where I add the smaller temp arrays according to the lead time for each iteration (not shown here). E.g. In iteration 1 I want the values in temp_lows[0] added to lows[0] and values in temp_lows[1] added to lows[1] and so on. 
Problem now, I cant seem to find a solution to continuously add the smaller arrays in the right dimension.

EDIT 1:
My question was not precise. temp_lows contains data for a certain lead time, which I called "lead". Now, for every iteration, I want the data I processed in this itration (temp_lows) to be added to the lows array at the right lead time, in a way that there is a continuous list. I will use these lists (lead 0 to 9) to generate a PDF function.

Comment: This more like a python list approach.  Numpy arrays aren't used like this.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to create another array with the final answer like this:

```
>>> newLows = np.concatenate((lows[:,np.newaxis], temp_lows), axis=1)
>>> newLows
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I’m not sure I’m quite following the logic of the edit, perhaps some actual data and expected result would help clarify it. 
In the meantime, maybe this is more like what you are looking for?

```
>>> newLows = np.array([np.concatenate((lows[lead], temp_lows[lead]), axis=None) for lead in range(10)])
...   
>>> newLows
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: In the way I asked, this would be the right answer. I am sorry I was unclear, but the ones are only placeholders for the data I work with. Please check my edit, where I made the question clearer (hopefully).

Comment: @MrFrogmog Are the data shapes the same?

Comment: lows is array of int32 (10,) and temp_lows is array of int32 (10,32), Is this what you mean?

Comment: @MrFrogmog , not sure if you saw it, but I did post a second solution to my answer that should do what your original code was attempting .

Comment: I think this comes close, but what if I want to extend every line (array element) with another array (1 Dimensions, in this case the temp_low from the next iteration)

Comment: @MrFrogmog I’m afraid you’ll have to post a more comprehensive list of requirements of what you might “want” to do. The code I posted completes the process in your question without the error you encountered

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is

```py
np.concatenate((lows[lead], temp_lows[lead]), axis=None)
```

returns an array, and you are trying to put that result into a single element slot of the array `lows`. I don't see the point of this, since every row is the same:

```py
[0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

There are far better ways to achieve the result, for example:

```py
>>> a = np.ones(shape=(10, 13), dtype=np.int64)
>>> a[:,0] -= 1
>>> a
[[0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: In the way I asked, this would be the right answer. I am sorry I was unclear, but the ones are only placeholders for the data I work with. Please check my edit, where I made the question clearer (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct list way of extending a list:

```
In [311]: lows = [[0] for lead in range(10)] 
     ...: temp_lows = [[1 for points in range(12)] for lead in range(10)] 
     ...: for lead in range(5): 
     ...:     lows[lead].extend(temp_lows[lead]) 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [312]: lows                                                                                         
Out[312]: 
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0],
 [0],
 [0],
 [0],
 [0]]
```